# Getting error: Error in UseMethod("filter") : no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "logical"

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I'm so confused because I thought that a logical expression is one of the parameters of a `filter()` function? Here is my code:

```
simplifyList <- function(x) {
    x <- x %>% {
        filter(x$Q26 == "Yes")
    }
}
simplifyList(a)
```

I've checked to make sure `a` is of the class `data.frame`, and adding `dplyr::` in front of `filter()` didn't do anything. I even updated the dplyr package in case that was the problem. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you used braces `{}` in the right-hand side of your piped expression

```r
x <- x %>% { ... }
```

*and* you referred directly to your dataset `x` in the `filter` expression

```r
filter(x$Q26 == "Yes")
```

Both of these are most likely incorrect. For the first one, see the help for `%>%`:

> **Using lambda expressions with %>%**
>
> Each rhs is essentially a one-expression body of a unary function. Therefore defining lambdas in magrittr is very natural, and as the definitions of regular functions: if more than a single expression is needed one encloses the body in a pair of braces, { rhs }. However, note that within braces there are no "first-argument rule": it will be exactly like writing a unary function where the argument name is "." (the dot).

So instead of `x %>% { <expression referring to x> }`, something like

```r
x <- x %>% { filter(.$Q26 == "Yes" }
```

would work. Or you could remove the braces and write

```r
x <- x %>% filter(x$Q26 == "Yes")
```

and that would also work. But what you REALLY want to do is

```r
x <- x %>% filter(Q26 == "Yes")
```

or simply

```r
x <- filter(x, Q26 == "Yes")
```

which avoids any issues to do with piping.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to fully diagnose without example data, but try:

```
simplifyList <- function(x) {
    x %>%
        filter(Q26 == "Yes")
}
simplifyList(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet figured out **why**, but the problem is that you should use `Q26 == "Yes"` rather than `x$Q26 == "Yes"`:

```r
library(dplyr)
dd <- data.frame(x=1:2, Q26=c("Yes","No"))
simplifyList <- function(x) { x <- x %>% filter(Q26=="Yes") ; return(x) }
simplifyList(dd)
```

It's far from obvious (to me) why `x$Q26` doesn't work - it must have to do with tidyverse's particular evaluation rules, or their interaction with evaluation of function arguments:

- `with(dd, identical(dd$Q26, Q26))` — which is how I would think to mimic tidyverse's rules — is TRUE.
- `dd %>% filter(dd$Q26 == "Yes")` works outside of a function ...

Answer (score 1):

You could make what you wrote work if you use the `{}` signs at the right locations:

```r
library(dplyr)

a <- data.frame(x = 1:2, Q26 = c("Yes","No"))

simplifyList <- function(x) {
  x <- x %>% 
    filter({{x}}$Q26 == "Yes")
  x
}

simplifyList(a)
#>   x Q26
#> 1 1 Yes
```

but I would not recommend you to use such unusual syntax.
Instead, I would either do this:

```r
simplifyList <- function(x) {
  x %>%
    filter(Q26 == "Yes")
}

simplifyList(a)
#>   x Q26
#> 1 1 Yes
```

or that:

```r
simplifyList <- function(x) {
  filter(.data = x, Q26 == "Yes")
}

simplifyList(a)
#>   x Q26
#> 1 1 Yes
```

I hope this helps…

<sup>Created on 2021-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>